# What values of $p$ give convergence to $0$ in $l^p$

Tags: sequences-and-series, metric-spaces, normed-spaces, lp-spaces

Given a sequence $x_n \in l^p$ whose first $n^2$ members equal $\frac {1}{n}$, and all other entries $=0$, for what values of $p$ does the sequence converge to the zero sequence in $l^p$?

So do I have to find the values of $p$ where the norm is finite? How do I do this?

Comment: For all values of $p$ the norm of $x_n$ is finite. However, you have to compute $\| x_\|_p$ for arbitrary $p$, and find the $p$ for which those norms converge to $0$ as $n \to \infty$. For convienence, it might be better to write $\| x_n \|_p^p$ for $p < \infty$ and show that this goes to zero.

Comment: What's \| x_\|_p?

Comment: $\| x_n\|_p$ is the $p$-norm of $x_n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$x_n$ converges to $0$ iff $\|x_n\|$ converges to $0$.  If $x_n=(x_{n,j})_{j\in N}$ and  $1\leq  p <\infty $ then $$\|x_n\|=(\sum_{j\in N}|x_{n,j}|^p)^{1/p}.$$ For $1\leq p<\infty $,  we have $$\|x_n\|^p=n^2n^{-p}=n^{2-p}$$ so $\|x_n\|=n^{(2/p)-1}$. This  converges to $0$ iff $(2/p)-1<0$ iff  $2<p$. For $p=\infty$ the def'n of $\|x_n\|$ is $$\|x_n\|=\sup_{j\in N}|x_{n,j}|$$so for $p=\infty$ we have $\|x_n\|=1/n$ which converges to $0$. Altogether we have convergence to $0$  iff $2<p\leq \infty.$

Comment: that is really clear, thanks!